# Eliminate parameter $t$ in a set of parametric equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

> **Question**: Given the set of parametric equations:
>
> $x = 2 \tan t$
>
> $y = 2 \cos^2 t$
>
> Eliminate the parameter $t$ and find the rectangular equation for the curve.

How would I go about solving this? I know that when the equations involve $\sin$ and $\cos$ I can simply square and add them to $1$ but I don't know of any comparable identity for $\tan$ and $\cos^2$.

Comment: you don't know an identity for tan^2 and 1/cos^2?

Comment: use $\sec^2(t) = 1 + \tan^2(t)$ as mentioned in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hint $\to$

Given (1)$\cos^2t$ +$\sin^2t$=1 , (2) $\tan t$ =$\frac{sint}{cost}$

x=2$\tan t$ =2$\frac{sint}{cost}$, $x^2$=4$\tan ^2t$=4$\frac{sin^2t}{cos^2t}$

with y=2$\cos^2t$ , you should be able to finish the rest from here.